# Drupal 7: Main menu not displaying child elements

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In my main menu, I have primary links and child links. The primary links are printing just fine. However, when I make a child element (by either dragging it to the right or selecting a parent link), they aren't displayed in the menu at all. I can create a new menu, and the child elements display correctly. I also ensured that 'Show as Expanded' was selected. Are child 'Main Menu' elements not suppose to show up?

Comment: I had something similar, here is my answer. [custom-mobile-menu-in-drupal-7-cant-access-child-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331774/custom-mobile-menu-in-drupal-7-cant-access-child-links/38483904#38483904)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All levels/childs of the menu stucture should be set in one menu tree (Main Menu in this case).

Now go to admin/structure/menu/settings and set your **Main Menu** to both **Source for the Main links** and **Source for the Secondary links**.

Answer (score 0):

Which theme are you using? If you using Bartik then that is your problem as the Bartik theme doesn't support drop down menus. See here http://drupal.org/node/1508652
The link includes a work-around